# I have had my phone stolen

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice, past-perfect

once i came across a phrase

> I have had my phone stolen

and

> I had had my ears removed

I understand the meaning, but what's the grammatical rule regulates it? 
I have googled passive voice, but found only examples like "My phone was stolen",
so don't really know what to google.

Comment: I really would like it if you could please change that second sentence. "I have had my **warts** removed". Thank you very much.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between “had had to” and “have had to”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/72478/9161) , [“have had” and “had had” for possession](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/82959/9161), [Necessity of using “had had” where a single “had” could have sufficed?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/9801/9161), [Until now + Past Perfect / Present Perfect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/202367/9161)

Comment: Also, [“He had had his nap” or “he had his nap”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/139764/9161)